# Access mysql db inside docker container from outside

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm learning to use docker to make my development easier but I'm still failing access mysql.

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev1
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER:  root
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dev1
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Wordpress is running without difficulties which means that mysql must be alright too. I'm on Linux and trying to connect database via mysql workbench. It appears that connection is also ok expect for, there is no schema and so no wordpress tables.

I tried to add also phpmyadmin into `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
  - db
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
restart: always
ports:
  - '8080:80'
environment:
  PMA_HOST: db
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
networks:
  - wpsite
```

but here I get following error after attempt to access db:
[image]

What I miss?

EDIT:
here is overview of running containers:
[image]

Comment: what does `docker-compose ps` show?

Comment: @Thomasleveil - I added screen  with command result to the post

Comment: Why not map your MySQL port as 33060:3306 then you can be sure in that inside your container you use 3306 and outside it you use 33060? You do this for http and that works ok

Comment: @Caius I had tried but my problem persisted.

Comment: What does `docker-compose exec db mysql -p -e "SHOW DATABASES"` show?

Comment: can you run `docker images | grep -e mysql -e phpmyadmin -e wordpress`so we can have the exact **image id** for each images .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i modified your docker-compose , with 2 small changes , and i dont have a issue .

I created a user for wordpress ( *userdev1* ) in mysql .

The **root** is already here and can have some restrictions for remote access .

Via **phpmyadmin** i can login with **userdev1** or **root**

You want a network access with the **root** account you must set this variable
MYSQL_ROOT_HOST .

You can find more information on this page  ( 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker_var_mysql-root-host  )

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password4root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev1
      MYSQL_USER: userdev1
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password4dev1
    networks:
      - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER:  userdev1
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password4dev1
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: dev1
    networks:
      - wpsite
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

** *UPDATED* **

With the very last version of mysql docker image ( aka mysql 8.0 ),
you must change the default-authentification to mysql_native_password to be comptatible with legacy mysql client

source : 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password

```
  image: mysql:latest
  command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Comment: Your code is working. However the real cause why my code didn't work is in image mysql. For some reason is needed "image: mysql:5.7" because "image: mysql:latest" causes my issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TomášVavřinka , i updated my response with a update for the last version of mysql ( aka 8.0 )